# (Non-trivial) Maths problems that don't require any formal maths education

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle, big-list

> Does anyone know good brain teasers that show the nature of
>   mathematics to people with little or no mathematical knowledge? Or do
>   you know a book with such problems?

**Criteria** are that the problem should be interesting, require no maths knowledge and be solvable by a mathematical core principle, e.g. a real proof. Ideally, the problem does not require calculations or at least not lengthy ones.

**Example** Remove two diagonal corner squares of a chess board. Is it possible to tile the board with a given number of domino stones? See this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242810/prove-or-disprove-a-chessboard-with-diagonal-corners-removed-cannot-be-tiled-wi?rq=1).

Comment: Martin Gardner has good books on mathematical puzzles that laymen can understand.

Comment: This one is fantastic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M64HUIJFTZM

Comment: Maybe this video [Donald in mathmagic land](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_ZHsk0-eF0) can be inspiring ? (personnaly, I think it's a very good video for novice and non novice as well since it really relate mathematic to concrete thing through a donald duck cartoon).

Comment: Take a look at "MathEducators" (sub)site : for example this recent question 
 https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/17864/how-do-i-show-students-the-beauty-of-mathematics

Answer (score 7):

Being very visual, I like synthetic figures.

One of my favorite figure is known as [Monge circles' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%27s_theorem):

[image]

Being given three non-intersecting circles in the general case (different radii), consider the external tangent lines of these circles taken two by two. They intersect in 3 points ; they look aligned. How can we prove it ?

If you have an audience, let them search for a short time. Then give the following hint "Think in 3D". Most often, one of the people in the audience will have the idea :

Imagine this "scene" as an "aerial view" of 3 spheres with the same radii as the circles before, placed on a plane floor, to which all the spheres are tangent. But there is a second plane tangent to the 3 spheres (this is our intuition, but it can also be established rigorously (*)). The intersection of this plane with the floor is "the" line we are looking for. If somebody has doubts, one can invoke a supplementary convincing argument dealing with the 3 "icecream cones" containing 2 balls.

(*) Remark: the centers of the spheres determine a plane which is the medial plane of the two tangent planes.

Edit :

Let us present now the **Desargues** configuration which has a striking similarity with the Monge problem. I will explain it using the notation of the following figure :

[image]

Consider two triangles $ABC$ and $A'B'C'$ which are perspective from a certain point P, meaning that lines $AA', \ BB', \ CC'$ meet in this point. Then intersection points

$$Q:= AB \cap A'B', \ R:= AC \cap A'C', \ S:= BC \cap B'C'$$

are aligned (the reciprocal is true).

How can this property can be established ? (question to the reader)

Answer : By the same way as before, this time by interpreting this figure as a 3D scene in which triangular pyramid with basis $ABC$ and apex $P$ is cut by a transversal plane. This plane intersects the base plane along a line on which necessarily $Q, \ R, \ S$ are situated.

Reference : [this page](http://web.mnstate.edu/peil/geometry/C4ProjectiveGeometry/7desargues.htm)
of an excellent geometry site. See as well fig. 2.9 page 18 of this well-written article by Bobenko [here](http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/%7Ebobenko/Lehre/Skripte/projective_part.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Martin Gardner in the introduction of his book,  Entertaining Mathematical Puzzles, writes that:

> [....] I have done
>   my best to find puzzles that are unusual and entertaining, that call for only the most elementary knowledge of
>   mathematics, but at the same time provide stimulating glimpses into
>   higher levels of mathematical thinking. [......]

Hence I think this is the book you are searching.

You can download PDF version of book from  [here](https://b-ok.cc/dl/710672/c94106)  , but if you like the book please do buy the book.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that all points af the plane are coloured either red or blue.  Prove that there is one color such that for any positive real $a$ there exist two points of that color with distance $a$.

Now prove the same provided all points of $\mathbb R^3$ are coloured in three colours.