# How many times harder is to think in 3D as compared with 2D?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, symmetry, dimension-theory-algebra

I'm a chemist, currently going through a course about molecular symmetry and group theory applied to Chemistry. This subject is very demanding in terms of visualization in 3D space. To really grasp the subject, one must be able to see, for example, how the orbitals around a given nucleus transform when subjected to the different symmetry operations in space.

I'm stumped by the sheer difficulty I have at it, specially given I deem myself good at reasoning with geometric concepts in the 2D plane. Add just one dimension and now it feels like to be in a quagmire.

That makes me wonder, can you put hard numbers in this increased overhead when going from 2D to 3D? How much more processing power is necessary to reason about 3D space? A linear scaling can be surely ruled out as, at least for me, 3D doesn't feel like just 50% more difficult. It feels like a several fold increase in complexity. Could be the case it scales like area or volume, as a power of the number of dimensions, say, n³? What about a generalization to higher dimensions? How much more difficult a 4D being would have reasoning about 4D as compared with 3D?

I would not be surprised if grasping something like a 4D were very difficult or even impossible for us, as we don't experience 4D spatial dimensions. But we do live in 3D space, and yet thinking in 3D can be very hard.

Comment: I think this depends. I have aphantasia and find 3D reasoning easier than 2D, because 3D I can imagine "touching" an object, rotating reflecting etc. To answer your question, I think something interactive like Wolfram for visualizing these shapes will greatly benefit you. I haven't met any person who can visualise 4D objects. I think it is better in that case to draw analogies with lower dimensions. For example, a 3D cube being a square that is "extruded", we can think the same way comparing a tesseract with a cube. You can resort to dozens of clever analogies if you actively look for them.

Comment: @LPenguin I didn't know "aphantasia" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphantasia) ; surprized that can abolish the barrier I have found among my students with great difficulty to visualize things in 3D (even in 2D...).

Comment: I've found that I can understand math without needing to visualize anything very complicated in 3D. The things I visualize are like: a plane, a point off the plane and the line connecting the point to the closest point on the plane. Or a sphere, or a surface and the boundary of the surface. Nothing harder than that. You might be able to find ways to understand these things that don't strain your powers of visualization so much.

Comment: @littleO Very interesting. I think that instructors (as me) should be more aware of the fact that "psychological" (I don't know how to call them) "blockages" can come from "good will attempts" to provide visual help...

Comment: My experience (from teaching linear algebra and vector calculus) suggests *strongly* that the ability to visualize 3D varies immensely from person to person. And is somewhat uncorrelated with their general intellectual/mathmatical ability. It is an oversimplification to say that *some have it - some don't*, but there is some truth to it. I warn my students that next we will go through some material that those of you who played with legos a lot as kids will have easier to handle.

Comment: (cont'd) When a lot younger I may have implied that they **should** have played with legos, but later in life i have learned that possibly it's the other way around. The people born with good 3D skills are also attracted to legos, those without less so. Anyway, my wife is probably generally more intelligent than I am, but she had trouble with this when taking extra courses in chemistry (to get more formal teaching competence). I once used our kid's toys to build a crude 3D model of some molecule to demonstrate how orientation (chirality) matters, and it all ended in tears.

Comment: (cont'd) I don't have either easy solutions or quantitative difficulty scales here. The answer depends on the person. Now that I have the technology I teach these topics using 3D-animations also. For obvious reasons those are not included in the lecture notes, on slides I actually can do that (if the students have Adobe Reader rather than just a browser). To let them revisit the animations I need videos or, preferrably, a computer lab, where they can use Mathematica (or equivalent). Videos I have just started (COVID), so I have no real idea how much those tools help.

Comment: I'm sure this theme has been researched. I hazard a guess that regulars at [MathEducators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions) would be better placed to point you at such studies based on more than my scant anecdotal data.

Comment: There's not just the question of how many dimensions, but what you are trying to do in those dimensions. Rotations in 2D can be represented by one linear parameter. Rotations in 3D take at least three parameters, and the space those parameters live in is topologically a 3-sphere (meaning the sphere you get by taking all points at radius 1 from the origin in 4-dimensional space). So I think it *is* several times more complicated to rotate things in 3D than in 2D.

Comment: A colleague of mine once quipped, "I know enough about three-dimensional space to walk around in it, but that's about all." That seems to sum things up for me, too, even though a major focus of my personal research has been on tetrahedra (and occasionally polyhedra); I just default to manipulating equations to get anything done. We might all get better at 3D stuff as augmented- and virtual-reality platforms give rise 3D "diagrams" to help us quantify what we see in space as readily as elaborate figures on the printed page have done for centuries.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is based on my experience.

Usually for me three-dimensional things are easier to imagine than two-dimensional those. This is because to imagine the first I have just to reproduce a slightly modified image from my daily life experience. The latter is mostly three-dimensional. In particular, I feel solid things more real than plain those.

This situation is typical. Nicholas Bourbaki wrote that “the mathematician does not work like a machine, nor as the workingman on a moving belt; we can not over-emphasize the fundamental role played in his research by a special intuition, which is not the popular sense-intuition, but rather a kind of direct divination (ahead of all reasoning) of the normal behavior, which he seems to have the right to expect of mathematical beings, with whom a long acquintance has made him as familiar as with the beings of the real world”.

So I think that for people like me visualization depends not on a processing power (especially on quantifiable one) but on experience. Also it can require some kind of psychical energy. For instance, for me can be hard to provide a detailed visualization when I am tired.

Hard cases can require to detailed study the object first, in order to “saturate” it in mind and then sometimes an image can be forced to flash in mind.

Probably a visualization skill can also be developed by performing visualization exercises, which can be found, for instance, in some parapsychological books.

A real visualization is hard for me. I mean, for instance, to imagine an object not as some related spatial intuition but a concrete image, for instance, a small red ball, which is seen as in real life or dream.

On visualization of high-dimensional things see my recent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804467/seeking-intuition-for-why-tesselations-of-space-by-hypercubes-in-dimensions-8-n).

Comment: I have had a look at the recent answer you mention: very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

It is often with examples that one can approach a subject.

I give here 5 *counter*-examples where 3D can be a "blessing" for understanding a 2D situation...

A) First, an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3608086) of mine some time ago about Monge and Desargues theorems.

B) A different situation where a family of curves can be more globally interpreted as a set of level curves on a surface. Consider for example the following representation of a double family of hyperbolas situated "on" the parabolic hyperboloid with equation $z=x^2-y^2$:

[image]

Remark: The horizontal sections are hyperbolas whereas the vertical sections are [parabolas](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Enmd/quadrics/hypparab.html).

C) Still with a level curve interpretation, but with a physical situation: the fact that sound waves emitted from one of the foci of an elliptical mirror are reflected on the mirror in such a way that they are eventually re-focalized into the other focus. You will find a description in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1680058) answer of mine (again !): begin by the last figure and consider the figure before this one as a oblique "lifting" in 3D of the 2D situation: just an issue of (shifted) level curves...

**Edit (Nov 16, 2020)**

D) Let me present here, still another case, with some common features with example C). Consider the first figure below:

[image]

It describes (in a classical way) a conical curve by a point (a focus), a line (its directrix) and a number $e$ (its eccentricity) as the set of points $M$ such that the distances' ratio (from the point to the focus and the shortest distance from the point to the directrix) is constant and equal to $e:

$$MF/MH = e\tag{1}$$

This process encompasses the three types of conic curves : ellipse if $e<1$, parabola if $e=1$, hyperbola if $e>1$.

Could this picture be seen in a different manner ? Yes, in the following way (second figure): we can transform  in a certain vertical plane our different types of curves in a unified type, i.e.,  circles, moreover concentric... with a well placed light source $S$:

[image]

In fact, afterwards, one can think to the different curves of the first figure as the limits of the light projected on the ground by a torchlight having an adjustable conical beam width...

**Remarks:**

The "mathematical machinery" behind the transformation seen in the second figure is "projective geometry" which has become a recognized branch of geometry in the 19th century, whereas the definition of conics we just saw using foci, directrix and eccentricity has $2300$ years...

2. Squaring relationship (1) gives a 2nd degree equation common to all conics:

$$x^2+y^2=e^2(1-x)^2.$$

E) See this recent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3908363) as well...

Comment: Wonderful examples, Jean Marie. Thank you. Now I see 3D can be used to connect things that apparently had no connection in 2D, for deeper understanding. But yet, taking the example pictured in the answer, if I try to picture what that surface would look like after some rotation in 3D, that is inherently more complicated than figuring out what a parabola or hyperbola would look like after some rotation in the xy plane. I'm still curious if this complexity increase can be precisely quantified. I will put a bounty in this question.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. I just added a 4th example.